# Simplificar metodo usando expresiones lambda

Tags: java, java-swing, bucle-for, revisión-de-código

Tengo este simple metodo:

```
public void setComboBoxItems(List<User> users, List<Client> clients) {
    for (User user : users) {
        usersIds.addItem(user.getId());
    }

    for (Client client : clients) {
        clientsIds.addItem(client.getId());
    }
}
```

Lo que hace es añadir items a 2 **JComboBox**, los items añadidos son los **ID** de los Users y Clients contenidos en las 2 listas de nombre **users-clients**.

Hay alguna forma de simplificar este metodo, tal vez llamando `users.forEach()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El objetivo mio era tener menos lineas de código y hacerlo con expresiones lambda, entonces lo que hice fue usar `.forEach`.

```
public void setComboBoxItems(List<User> users, List<Client> clients) {
    users.forEach(user -> usersIds.addItem(user.getId()));
    clients.forEach(client -> clientsIds.addItem(client.getId()));
}
```

Que hace prácticamente lo mismo que el metodo anterior.

Digamos que podría haber hecho algo como esto:

```
public void setComboBoxItems(List<User> users, List<Client> clients) {
    for (User user : users) {usersIds.addItem(user.getId());}
    for (Client client : clients) {clientsIds.addItem(client.getId());}
}
```

El mismo código de antes pero tratando de ahorrar espacio pero no es lo que busco ya que mi objetivo es aprender y hacer uso de expresiones lambda.

Comment: y si por favor añades una explicación para que el resto de la comunidad entendamos tu proceder?